# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Laptop Completely Freezes When Hitting the Caps Lock Key

Tags: 18.04, laptop

Title pretty much says it all. Razer Blade Stealth, Intel Graphics 620 Kaby Lake, Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4, 64-Bit 18.04.3. I am perfectly ok just disabling the caps lock key since I rarely ever use it.

Comment: is this repeatable ?   did you assign to that key some macro to get launched

Comment: Yes, I found out that pressing the caps lock once is fine but when you turn it off, the computer completely freezes

Answer (score 0):

Installing the razer keyboard driver which you can find here:
https://terrycain.github.io/razer-drivers/

After installing the driver you should see it doing
$ lsmod | grep "razerkbd"

Comment: I installed the drivers and used polychromatic but it is saying my device is connected but not recognized